# bot.startPolling or bot.launch stopped working after few hours telegraf js (bot not responding or sending any messages)

Tags: javascript, bots, telegram-bot, telegraf.js

I have this simple code Telegraf JS

```
bot.command('starttahabot', (ctx) => {
    ctx.reply('Hello');
});
//bot.launch()
bot.startPolling()
```

I tried these two functions, launch and startPolling and after few hours the bot is stopped working and not responding anymore

Can anyone help